# Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 20.04, dkms

The problem occurred on my PC with Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070.

I tried to install the newest CUDA SDK and had problems with drivers so following various tutorials so following many tutorials I purged Nvidia drivers being willing to install newer ones, but after reboot choosing Ubuntu in GRUB, I get no signal (a blank screen).

To fix it I had run Ubuntu Recovery Mode (with internet connection) with root terminal and tried to install drivers. The problem is that I am unable to install any Nvidia drivers now because the dkms package is missing and I cannot install it, constantly giving this message:

`E: Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate`

Does anyone have an idea how could I install dkms and so as the drivers and get my Ubuntu running properly again?

Results of `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt install dkms`:

[image]

Comment: please edit your question with the full, unredacted outputs of `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt install dkms`.  When you boot into recovery, did you remember to enable networking?  Without this step the file system is mounted read-only and you also won't have any internet access (so you won't be able to install or update software from the internet)

Comment: @Nmath done. I hope the picture is readable?

Comment: I don't see the `main` repository enabled.  Run `sudo add-apt-repository main` and then try installing `dkms` again.

Comment: Thank you @Terrance - it fixed the problem and everything is working properly again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding repository *main* using:

`sudo apt-add-repository main`

fixed the problem.